# Azure Data Factory Event Trigger - Storage Account Key in Json?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-eventgrid

we have a storage account that is locked down. My pipeline has connections that reference a key vault to get the access token for the storage account.

When I create an event trigger in ADF, ADF lets me find and connect to the storage account (without asking for a key or prompting me to select the linked service connection). It tells me what files it will include based on my begins with and ends with values (it found 2 files). It saves successfully.

When I publish it, I get this error in between publish to adf-publish and generating the arm templates.

---

The attempt to configure storage notifications for the provided storage account ****failed. Please ensure that your storage account meets the requirements described at https://aka.ms/storageevents. The error is Failed to retrieve credentials for request=RequestUri=https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/********/resourceGroups/&lt;resource group name&gt;/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage account name here to gen 2 data lake>/listAccountSas, Method=POST, response=StatusCode=400, StatusDescription=Bad Request, IsSuccessStatusCode=False, Content=System.Net.HttpWebResponse, responseContent={&#34;error&#34;:{&#34;code&#34;:&#34;InvalidValuesForRequestParameters&#34;,&#34;message&#34;:&#34;Values for request parameters are invalid: keyToSign.&#34;}}

---

I believe this is due to the fact that ADF trigger creation process (and therefore its JSON) does not allow you to point to a Key Vault to get the access token for the storage account you are connecting to. Is this the issue? Is there a fix for this?

Appreciate any help, thanks - April

Comment: Now I'm facing exactly this issue, Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the storage account is attached to a VNET and running behind the firewall. I faced similar issue because of this. You may remove the firewall once and configure the trigger and then bring the firewall back.

Answer (score 0):

It's not strictly necessary to disable the firewall. You can also use this feature on your storage account.

[image: Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account]